# SQL Alter Trigger hanging

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2000

I'm trying to alter an SQL Server 2000 update trigger, but its hanging and hanging and hanging.  Why might this be happening and what can I do to get around it?  It is a long trigger, could that be why?

Trigger code is long, but abbreviated below:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[UP_AL_ItemUPCs] ON [dbo].[AL_ItemUPCs] 

FOR UPDATE

  AS

  SET XACT_ABORT ON

  Declare @vError varchar(254)
  Declare @iUpdateCount int

  Select @iUpdateCount = Count ( D.UPCID ) 
    From deleted D

  If @iUpdateCount > 1  
    Begin
       Raiserror ( 'This Table maintains AVANTI data ... mass updates cannot be done, yet' , 16 , 1 )      
       Rollback
       Goto Exit_
    End

  Declare @iUpdateCheck int
  Declare @OldItemNumber varchar(50)
  Declare @ItemNumber varchar(50)
  Declare @OldItemPrefix varchar(5)
  Declare @ItemPrefix varchar(5)
  Declare @OldItemCode varchar(25)
  Declare @ItemCode varchar(25)
  Declare @OldItemSuffix varchar(5)
  Declare @ItemSuffix varchar(5)
  Declare @vOldCustomerCode varchar(24)
  Declare @vNewCustomerCode varchar(24)

  If Update ( [CustomerCode] )
    Begin
      Select @vOldCustomerCode  = D.CustomerCode , @vNewCustomerCode = U.CustomerCode
        From  deleted D
        Inner Join inserted U On D.UPCID = U.UPCID
    End
  Else
    Begin
      Select @vOldCustomerCode  = U.CustomerCode , @vNewCustomerCode =  U.CustomerCode 
          From deleted D
         Inner Join AL_ItemUPCs  U On D.UPCID = U.UPCID
    End

 If Update ( ItemPrefix ) Or Update ( ItemCode ) Or Update ( ItemSuffix ) 
    Begin

    If Update ( ItemPrefix ) 
      Begin
        Select @OldItemPrefix = D.ItemPrefix  ,  @ItemPrefix =  U.ItemPrefix 
          From deleted D
         Inner Join inserted U On D.UPCID = U.UPCID
      End
    Else
      Begin
        Select @OldItemPrefix = U.ItemPrefix  ,  @ItemPrefix =  U.ItemPrefix 
          From deleted D
         Inner Join AL_ItemUPCs  U On D.UPCID = U.UPCID
      End

    If Update ( ItemCode ) 
      Begin
        Select @OldItemCode = D.ItemCode ,  @ItemCode =  U.ItemCode
          From deleted D
         Inner Join inserted U On D.UPCID = U.UPCID
      End
    Else
      Begin
        Select @OldItemCode = IsNull ( U.ItemCode , '' )   ,  @ItemCode =  IsNull ( U.ItemCode , '' )
          From deleted D
         Inner Join AL_ItemUPCs U On D.UPCID = U.UPCID
      End

    If Update ( ItemSuffix ) 
      Begin
        Select @OldItemSuffix= D.ItemSuffix ,  @ItemSuffix =  U.ItemSuffix
          From deleted D
         Inner Join inserted U On D.UPCID = U.UPCID
      End
    Else
      Begin
        Select @OldItemSuffix = IsNull ( U.ItemSuffix , '' )   ,  @ItemSuffix =  IsNull ( U.ItemSuffix , '' )
          From deleted D
         Inner Join AL_ItemUPCs U On D.UPCID = U.UPCID
      End

    Set @OldItemNumber = @OldItemPrefix + '-' + @OldItemCode 
    Set @ItemNumber = @ItemPrefix + '-' + @ItemCode

    If @OldItemNumber = @ItemNumber Goto Skip_ItemUpdate

      Set @iUpdateCheck = 0

      Select @iUpdateCheck = @iUpdateCheck + IsNull ( Count ( recid )  , 0 )
        From [AVANTISERVER\NCL_MASTER].AVANTI.dbo.InventoryTrans C
      Where C.InvItemNumber =@OldItemNumber

--        Inner Join deleted D On C.InvItemNumber = D.ItemPrefix + '-' + D.ItemCode + IsNull ( D.ItemSuffix , '' ) 

      Select @iUpdateCheck = @iUpdateCheck +  IsNull ( Count ( recid )  , 0 ) 
        From [AVANTISERVER\NCL_MASTER].AVANTI.dbo.InventoryLocations C
      Where C.LocItemNumber =@OldItemNumber
          And C.LocQtyOnHand <> 0 

--        Inner Join deleted D On C.LocItemNumber = D.ItemPrefix + '-' + D.ItemCode + IsNull ( D.ItemSuffix , '' ) 

      Select @iUpdateCheck = @iUpdateCheck + IsNull ( Count ( * ) , 0 ) 
        From [AVANTISERVER\NCL_MASTER].AVANTI.dbo.JobItems C
      Where C.Item_Code = @OldItemNumber

--        Inner Join deleted D On C.Item_Code = D.ItemPrefix + '-' + D.ItemCode + IsNull ( D.ItemSuffix , '' ) 

      If @iUpdateCheck > 0 
        Begin
           Raiserror ( ' Item(s) cannot be updated due to associated AVANTI information ! ' , 16 , 1 )
           Rollback
           Goto Exit_
       End

     Update [AVANTISERVER\NCL_MASTER].Avanti.dbo.InventoryHeader Set [AVANTISERVER\NCL_MASTER].Avanti.dbo.InventoryHeader.ItemNumber = @ItemNumber
         From [AVANTISERVER\NCL_MASTER].Avanti.dbo.InventoryHeader AI 
      Where AI.ItemNumber = @OldItemNumber And AI.ColourStyle = @vOldCustomerCode

      Insert Into AL_ItemUPCChanges ( UPCID , ChangeType , FieldName , NewValue , OldValue )
      Select D.UPCID , 'Update' , 'ItemNumber' , @ItemNumber , @OldItemNumber
        From  deleted D
        Inner Join inserted U On D.UPCID = U.UPCID

      Insert Into AL_ItemUPCChanges ( UPCID , ChangeType , FieldName , NewValue , OldValue )
      Select D.UPCID , 'Update' , 'ItemPrefix' , U.ItemPrefix , D.ItemPrefix
        From  deleted D
        Inner Join inserted U On D.UPCID = U.UPCID
     Where D.ItemPrefix <> U.ItemPrefix

      Insert Into AL_ItemUPCChanges ( UPCID , ChangeType , FieldName , NewValue , OldValue )
      Select D.UPCID , 'Update' , 'ItemCode' , U.ItemCode , D.ItemCode
        From  deleted D
        Inner Join inserted U On D.UPCID = U.UPCID
     Where D.ItemCode <> U.ItemCode

      Insert Into AL_ItemUPCChanges ( UPCID , ChangeType , FieldName , NewValue , OldValue )
      Select D.UPCID , 'Update' , 'ItemSuffix' , U.ItemSuffix , D.ItemSuffix
        From  deleted D
        Inner Join inserted U On D.UPCID = U.UPCID
     Where D.ItemSuffix <> U.ItemSuffix


     Update AL_PO Set AL_PO.ItemCode = @ItemNumber
         From deleted I
         Inner Join AL_PO PO On I.UPCID = PO.UPCID
       Where PO.Status <> 'Closed'

    End

Skip_ItemUpdate:


  If Update ( [CustomerCode] )
    Begin

     Update [AVANTISERVER\NCL_MASTER].Avanti.dbo.InventoryHeader Set [AVANTISERVER\NCL_MASTER].Avanti.dbo.InventoryHeader.ColourStyle = U.CustomerCode
        From deleted D
        Inner Join inserted U On D.UPCID = U.UPCID
        Inner Join [AVANTISERVER\NCL_MASTER].Avanti.dbo.InventoryHeader AI On AI.ItemNumber = @ItemNumber  And AI.ColourStyle = @vOldCustomerCode

      Insert Into AL_ItemUPCChanges ( UPCID , ChangeType , FieldName , NewValue , OldValue )
      Select D.UPCID , 'Update' , 'CustomerCode' , U.CustomerCode , D.CustomerCode
        From  deleted D
        Inner Join inserted U On D.UPCID = U.UPCID
     Where D.CustomerCode <> U.CustomerCode

    End

  If Update ( [UPC] )
    Begin

      Insert Into AL_ItemUPCChanges ( UPCID , ChangeType , FieldName , NewValue , OldValue )
      Select D.UPCID , 'Update' , 'UPC' , U.UPC , D.UPC
        From  deleted D
        Inner Join inserted U On D.UPCID = U.UPCID
     Where D.UPC <> U.UPC

    End

  If Update ( [ImageName] )
    Begin

      Insert Into AL_ItemUPCChanges ( UPCID , ChangeType , FieldName , NewValue , OldValue )
      Select D.UPCID , 'Update' , 'ImageName' , U.ImageName , D.ImageName
        From  deleted D
        Inner Join inserted U On D.UPCID = U.UPCID
     Where D.ImageName <> U.ImageName

    End

  If Update ( [Description] )
    Begin

     Update [AVANTISERVER\NCL_MASTER].Avanti.dbo.InventoryHeader Set [AVANTISERVER\NCL_MASTER].Avanti.dbo.InventoryHeader.[Description] = Cast ( U.[Description]  as varchar(60) ),
         [AVANTISERVER\NCL_MASTER].Avanti.dbo.InventoryHeader.OldDescription = Cast ( U.[Description] As varchar(60) )
        From deleted D
        Inner Join inserted U On D.UPCID = U.UPCID
        Inner Join [AVANTISERVER\NCL_MASTER].Avanti.dbo.InventoryHeader AI On AI.ItemNumber = @ItemNumber And AI.ColourStyle = @vNewCustomerCode

     Insert Into AL_ItemUPCChanges ( UPCID , ChangeType , FieldName , NewValue , OldValue )
      Select D.UPCID , 'Update' , 'Description' , U.[Description] , D.[Description]
        From  deleted D
        Inner Join inserted U On D.UPCID = U.UPCID
     Where D.[Description] <> U.[Description]

    End

  If Update ( [Box] )
    Begin

      Insert Into AL_ItemUPCChanges ( UPCID , ChangeType , FieldName , NewValue , OldValue )
Select D.UPCID , 'Update' , 'Box' , U.[Box] , D.[Box]
        From  deleted D
        Inner Join inserted U On D.UPCID = U.UPCID
     Where D.[Box] <> U.[Box]

    End

  If Update ( [QtyPerBox] )
    Begin

      Insert Into AL_ItemUPCChanges ( UPCID , ChangeType , FieldName , NewValue , OldValue )
      Select D.UPCID , 'Update' , 'QtyPerBox' , U.[QtyPerBox] , D.[QtyPerBox]
        From  deleted D
        Inner Join inserted U On D.UPCID = U.UPCID
     Where D.[QtyPerBox] <> U.[QtyPerBox]

    End

  If Update ( [TransFat] )
    Begin

      Insert Into AL_ItemUPCChanges ( UPCID , ChangeType , FieldName , NewValue , OldValue )
      Select D.UPCID , 'Update' , 'TransFat' , U.[TransFat] , D.[TransFat]
        From  deleted D
        Inner Join inserted U On D.UPCID = U.UPCID
     Where D.[TransFat] <> U.[TransFat]

    End

  If Update ( [Length] )
    Begin

     Update [AVANTISERVER\NCL_MASTER].Avanti.dbo.InventoryHeader Set [AVANTISERVER\NCL_MASTER].Avanti.dbo.InventoryHeader.Size1 = U.Length
        From deleted D
        Inner Join inserted U On D.UPCID = U.UPCID
        Inner Join [AVANTISERVER\NCL_MASTER].Avanti.dbo.InventoryHeader AI On AI.ItemNumber = @ItemNumber And AI.ColourStyle = @vNewCustomerCode

      Insert Into AL_ItemUPCChanges ( UPCID , ChangeType , FieldName , NewValue , OldValue )
      Select D.UPCID , 'Update' , 'Length' , U.[Length] , D.[Length]
        From  deleted D
        Inner Join inserted U On D.UPCID = U.UPCID
     Where D.[Length] <> U.[Length]

    End

  If Update ( [Height] )
    Begin

     Update [AVANTISERVER\NCL_MASTER].Avanti.dbo.InventoryHeader Set [AVANTISERVER\NCL_MASTER].Avanti.dbo.InventoryHeader.Size2 = U.Height
        From deleted D
        Inner Join inserted U On D.UPCID = U.UPCID
        Inner Join [AVANTISERVER\NCL_MASTER].Avanti.dbo.InventoryHeader AI On AI.ItemNumber =@ItemNumber And AI.ColourStyle = @vNewCustomerCode

      Insert Into AL_ItemUPCChanges ( UPCID , ChangeType , FieldName , NewValue , OldValue )
      Select D.UPCID , 'Update' , 'Height' , U.[Height] , D.[Height]
        From  deleted D
        Inner Join inserted U On D.UPCID = U.UPCID
     Where D.[Height] <> U.[Height]  

    End

--Similar blocks ommitted for brevity

  If Update ( [FileRevision] )
    Begin

      Insert Into AL_ItemUPCChanges ( UPCID , ChangeType , FieldName , NewValue , OldValue )
      Select D.UPCID , 'Update' , 'FileRevision' , U.[FileRevision] , D.[FileRevision]
        From  deleted D
        Inner Join inserted U On D.UPCID = U.UPCID
     Where D.[FileRevision] <> U.[FileRevision]

    End
Exit_:
```

Comment: Is it being blocked? Did you check `sysprocesses` or `sp_who2`?

Comment: @AaronBertrand -Looks like a select statement with Runnable status is blocking me...  Not sure what that means though

Comment: Yes. In `sp_who2` (from a different window) you might see a value in the `BlkBy` column for the SPID in your original window where you're trying to commit the change. However I think your synopsis that the trigger is "too long" is also valid - how on earth does anyone maintain all that logic?

Comment: I don't know either, because I don't know what that `SELECT` statement is, or why it's running as long as it is. I hesitate to suggest you `KILL` it but rather figure out what it is and why it's taking so long. An `ALTER TRIGGER` should be a relatively quick DDL action but it does need exclusive access to underlying objects... so you may want to schedule your alter for a maintenance window or at least a period of relatively quiet activity.

Comment: @AaronBertrand -I don't know, I'm trying to maintain (I didn't write), and its a nightmere.  Causing all sorts of timeouts from the frontend.  That's why I'm refactoring, first I want to combine the remote server update queries (I'm hoping that will speed things up a bit).

Comment: @AaronBertrand You'll find out right quick whose process it is when you `KILL` it :)

Comment: @AaronBertrand -Ok, found out whose, asked them to close their frontend.  Trigger went right away.  So mystery solved.

Comment: @Yuck -Yeah, and if its the wrong person I might be polishing my resume.  Glad I didn't have to resort to that.

Comment: Glad it helped. Converting my comments to an answer in case it helps other users.

Comment: @AaronBertrand -I'm not sure what runnable status actually means though?  It sounds like it was an access frontend just sitting open but not doing anything.

Comment: is [AVANTISERVER\NCL_MASTER] available?

Comment: @devio -Yes, being used by dozens of users.  Doesn't seem to be an issue there.

Comment: I think you'll see runnable status for things like Open Table or the Access equivalent if there are locks being held on an object even though there is no current activity against it.

Comment: I hate to be the bearer of bad news but your trigger process is flawed and should be rewritten. You havea assumed that the deleted table will only have one record which is a horribly bad assumption. You need to process batches of records (called a set) not one at a time. If someone deletes a group of records in one delete query this trigger willl not work. Triggers in SQL server are NOT Row based.

Comment: @HLGEM -I know, its super ugly!  But (somehow) its been working, so I have to be careful about changes.  Don't want to make it worse.  What is does is prevent any changes that are for more than 1 record, so its actually working.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is it being blocked? Did you check `sysprocesses` or `sp_who2`? Run the following:

```
EXEC sp_who2;
```

(Run it from a different window.)

You might see a value in the `BlkBy` column for the row that matches the SPID in your original window where you're trying to commit the change. Then you can look at *that* SPID's row(s) in the same result and see what they're running. To determine what it is exactly you can use:

```
DBCC INPUTBUFFER(x);
```

(Replace 'x' with the SPID that is causing the blocking.)

If you determine that this session is disposable, you can run:

```
KILL x;
```

(Again replacing 'x' with the SPID.)

However that should be a last resort - before issuing `KILL` I suggest you rather figure out what it is and why it's taking so long. An `ALTER TRIGGER` should be a relatively quick DDL action but it does need exclusive access to underlying objects... so you may want to schedule your alter for a maintenance window or at least a period of relatively quiet activity.

Comment: -Fantastic summary of how to figure out this issue.  I'm done with using Enterprise Manager to analyze these things, its nowhere near as helpful as this method.

Comment: -ha ha!  Running DBCC Inputbugger([spid]) CAUSES a runnable process not doing anything!  But that one doesn't block anything.

Comment: Yeah I misspell `INPUTBUFFER` in that exact same way all the time.

Comment: Thanks for the great response and the detailed explanations!  You are an awesome person!